# installation of driver permission denied

Tags: installation, drivers, permissions

I am trying to install a driver but after antony@antony and password etc
cd /home/you-user-name/Downloads and then typed
 ./ati-driver-installer-11-12-x86.x86_64.run
I get permission denied.
Can someone tell me how to solve this install to the driver please or how to go about doing it a better way.

Ok the commands
chmod u+x ati-driver-installer-11-x86.x86_64.run
sudo ./ati-driver-installer-11-x86.x86_64.run
Didnt work

So Using the file permission suggested by Javier the driver runs but I get the follow message.
You are running a x86 machine with libc5

you need to run this installer as the super user.
Any suggestions? or should I open a new question

Should I use the restricted drivers utility and if so how do I do that?

Catalyst gives me..
For further configuration of the driver, please run anticonfig  from a terminal or AMD CCC:LE from desktop Manager Menu..
 I ran sudo aticonfig --initial after antony@antony  and got command not found.

uname -a gives 3.0.0-12-generic hash20-ubuntu SMP

The ati site is offering a the same driver for 32b again the _64.run at http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx  is it a problem at ati.com or should I update 11.10 32b to 64b and start again?

Thanks

Comment: BTW: Have you tried to use the restricted drivers utility?

Comment: @JavierRivera..No I dont think so how do I do that?

Comment: the kernel you have installed - is that from the 32bit ubuntu desktop install CD or something else?

Comment: @fossfreedom .. I installed 11.10 x32 to cd and installed from there. thanks

Comment: ok - I'm a little confused with the question you have now - have you managed to install the driver?  Is the only thing you havent done is run `sudo aticonfig --initial` to complete the installation?

Comment: @fossfreedom.. Ok I am stopped at trying to get the driver in as you told me it was 64b but its whats on ati site. Are you now saying its right?  tried sudo aticonfig --initial as you said gives command not found. do I need to run this from a particular directory?

Comment: This is getting to crowed to be useful in the future... but open the dash and type restricted, you should found a program to help you install the drivers (if it works there is no need to manually download them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be two problems here, you could need superuser rights to be able to execute the file and the file should have execute permissions. So try:

```
chmod u+x ati-driver-installer-11-x86.x86_64.run
sudo ./ati-driver-installer-11-x86.x86_64.run
```

Both command should be run after cding to Downloads.

You can also assign execute permissions using the GUI. Rigth click the file and select properties. In the new window go to the permission, you should be able to change it from there.

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks see above I have modified the question as its moved along a little thanks